# Would a hole in the ground with schach over the hole constitute a kosher sukkah?

Tags: halacha, sukkah, sukkot

If a hole was dug in the ground with 4 sides, would the 4 sides constitute walls that can be used for a sukkah?

Answer (score 5):

Shulchan aruch Orach chaim 633, 10 talks about digging a hole in the ground to compensate 10 tefachim e.g if the Sechach is 1 tefach high one compensates with 9 tefachim deep. As long as the 1 tefach walls above the ground are less than 3 tefachim horizontal distance (lavud) from the underground walls.

The Magen Avraham states that had the walls underground been the height of 10 tefachim, one would be alowed up to just under 4 amos (24 tefachim) horzontal distance from the above-ground walls as we only say *dofen akuma* with 10 tefach walls.

> נמוכה מעשרה וחקק בה להשלימה לעשרה ויש בחקק שיעור הכשר סוכה אם אין בין חקק לכותל ג"ט פסולה. ולא אמרי' דופן עקומה דלא איקרי דופן כלל כיון דאינו גבוה י

So clearly they are consdered Sukkah walls even 10 tefachim underground as illustrated by the Magen Avraham.